# TYPO3 7.6.32 How to add "text and media' and keep css_styled_content

Tags: typo3

I need a quick fix for TYPO3 v.7.6.32 as to add/display a video as a 'Text and Media' element, within a News element. Also, I wish to stay with  css_styled_content. My hope is that somebody developed a (tiny?) extension to achieve what I need.

I know that TYPO3 v7 has reached its end-of-life, but I need to just update a few records,  I am not ready for a general update.

Comment: try not including "fluid_styled_content" in the root template includes. The news plugin has content elements relations you may be able to use.

Comment: But you could rebuild with TYPO3 v11 , but if you can't I get it, but that is the best thing to do

Comment: @Rustyjim I never updated to fluid since I am not sure how to migrate my records. My hope is that somebody had developed an extension to add  'Text and Media' to 7.6.32 css_styled_content, or maybe just a way to upload and display a .mp4 video within a News record.

Comment: is it possible in your version of news, to add content elements?

Comment: @Rustyjim Yes, I have 'Text and Image', i do not have 'Text and Media'.